# Could a Ben Pekuah make all cattle not eligible for Shechitah?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, slaughter-shochet-shecht

According to the Simlah Chadashah, the definitive work on Shechitah, a Ben Pekuah does not need Shechitah on a Torah level however the child of a Ben Pekuah and regular animal would not be eligible for Shechitah since its considered half slaughtered already. See the link below for the relevant English translation of the halacha.

My question is, based on this halacha, should we not be concerned that at some point in the past a Ben Pekuah bred into the regular cattle population and therefore all their descendants should have this issue also?

https://books.google.com/books?id=U_ImCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA67&ots=VSd5y0JY2X&dq=simlah%20chadashah%20ben%20pekuah&pg=PA66#v=onepage&q=simlah%20chadashah%20ben%20pekuah&f=false

Answer (score 1):

Not if there aren't substantial numbers of bnei pakuah- we can apply 'rov.'

Comment: Welcome! You may want to add a source to make your answer more credible.

Answer (score 0):

See footnote 272 https://books.google.com/books?id=U_ImCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA67&ots=VSd5y0JY2X&dq=simlah%20chadashah%20ben%20pekuah&pg=PA66#v=onepage&q=simlah%20chadashah%20ben%20pekuah&f=false

However, Rashi explains [Chulin 75b] the problem is only on the first generation where the genetic code is 50% BP/50% Regular - the problem being that Shechitah requires cutting the MAJORITY of both Simanim which this beast does not have.
However, the next generation down, i.e. if this hybrid breeds with a regular beast, it will have a 75/25 ratio i.e. more than half of Kosher Simanim ready for Shechitah.

Some are confused by Rashi's comment that there is a Pessul of SheHiYa - which they think will also disqualify the 75/25. But this is an error. Rashi employs this argument of SheHiYa only to address the question he asks - why can the 2 Shechitas not be combined to provide a full Kosher Shechitah? [i.e. the Shechitah that is genetic meaning from the parent that is a BP which makes half the Simanim AS THOUGH they are Shechted, why can that not complement the Shechiath performed now with a knife? This Rashi explains cannot work because although they ARE compatible, nevertheless they cannot be combined due to ShehHiYa]

Comment: The genetic code has nothing to do with the existence of the kosher simanim. The animal is a regular kosher animal with all the kosher simanim. It is only that the mother was slaughtered. This has no physical effect. It is only a spiritual effect.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Meir and thanks for this first answer. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!